# Breeze Json uriBuilder

Tags: node.js, sails.js, breeze, waterline

I'm trying to use breeze.js with sails.js.

Therefore I'm using the breeze json uriBuilder.
I logged the req.query and got the following:

```
{ '{"where":{"name":"foo"},"orderBy":': { '"name"': '' } }
```

To query waterline objects I need to bring it into a format like this:

```
{ where: { name: 'foo' }, sort: 'name' }
```

First thing I tried:

```
var queryString = JSON.parse(Object.keys(req.query)[0]);
```

That works as long as I only put a where clause in. But with more parameters i get this strangely formatted json object. 
How can I parse it to get the correct object?

Solution:

Don't parse he req.query. Parse the url and parse it. This way u will get a json uery that sails accepts. Now strip of unsupported parameters as select and you're done.

```
var parsedUrl = urlUtils.parse(req.url, true);

var jsonQueryString = Object.keys(parsedUrl.query)[0];
var jsonQuery = JSON.parse(jsonQueryString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!  We haven't yet documented this adequately, but the basic idea is that there is a breeze-client npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/breeze-client) that you can use to parse the incoming json query into a breeze EntityQuery instance, from there you can interrogate the EntityQuery and turn it into whatever server side syntax you want, i.e. in your case Sails.)

```
// req = the HTTP request object.
var resourceName = req.params.slug; // the HTTP endpoint
var entityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery.fromUrl(req.url, resourceName);
// you would write the transform to sails below.
var sailsQuery = tranformToSails(entityQuery);
```

This is exactly what we do in the breeze-sequelize npm package where we take the incoming req.query and go thru the process above to create a 'Sequelize' query.

See http://www.getbreezenow.com/sequelize-mysqlpostgressql-lite

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot! For other sails users I'll do an edit to my question.